# Ruby error : undefined method `load_yaml' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError) when using Heroku's foreman start

Tags: ruby, heroku, rvm, foreman

I'm starting to play with Heroku to deploy a simple Node.js in their free plan. But when I run `foreman start`, I see this error :

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/builder.rb:10: undefined method `load_yaml' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1110:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1110
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:2:in `require'
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/process.rb:2
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:3:in `require'
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/engine.rb:3
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/cli.rb:3:in `require'
    from /usr/local/foreman/lib/foreman/cli.rb:3
    from /usr/bin/foreman:13:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/foreman:13
```

Problem : I know close to nothing to the Ruby platform, I don't use. I just happened to have rvm installed on my machine because I once wanted to play Octopress (Blog generator based on Jekyll). I first searched the internet, but couldn't find anything. I also visited the official RVM site and followed the troubleshooting basic steps : I ran `rvm stable` (which just produced no output...), ensured the call to the RVM script came last in my `~/.bash_profile`, and yes I'm using bash.

Here's the info I can give so you can help me.

I'm under OS X 10.6.8.

`rvm list` prints :

```
rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
```

`which ruby` prints :

`/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby`

`rvm info` prints :

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290:

  system:
    uname:       "Darwin djebbz 10.8.0 Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386 i386"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin10.0)"
    zsh:         "/bin/zsh => zsh 4.3.9 (i386-apple-darwin10.0)"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.8.3 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.2p290"
    date:         "2011-07-09"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin10.8.0"
    patchlevel:   "2011-07-09 revision 32553"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
    ruby:         "/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/khalid_jebbari/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/khalid_jebbari/bin/bin:/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290:/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/khalid_jebbari/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: It appears that foreman is using your system ruby, not the ruby from rvm.  What does the #! of foreman look like?

Comment: What is the `#!` of foreman ?

Comment: it looks like below fixed it, the #! is the line at the top of foreman script that tells it where to run ruby from, was curious as to what that was set to, since as mpapis said path was set wrong.

Comment: Oh ok : it says #!/usr/bin/ruby, so it's like it's hardcoded in foreman.

Comment: yeah, when foreman was intalled it was installed using the system ruby so it picked up that path, as opposed to the rvm one for the shebang (#!) line. so it was using the system ruby. My guess is that foreman was installed before you had rvm or rvm was set set to system, that is why the gem wasn't working.

Comment: I got it, pretty sure this is what happened. Thank you mate ! I will now always `rvm set` before installing anything that uses Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` is not set properly, my guess is you reset or preset PATH, use ruby to make it working:

```
rvm use 1.9.2-p290
```

and install foreman:

```
gem install foreman
```

Comment: It worked ! I think it's the `gem install foreman` that solved the problem, since I did run `rvm use XXX`. Strange, because foreman is supposed to be part of the Heroku Toolbelt .pkg...

Comment: Long months after, I removed rvm and switched to rbenv. Still don't know nothing about the ruby platform, but it feels less hacky and far simpler.